# when i choose photo from gallery or take a picture from camera my photo is rotating?

Tags: android, bitmap, rotation, imageview, gallery

im choosing a photo from gallery or taking a picture from camera and when it sets to an ImageView it's getting rotate , how can i fix it to become without rotate ?

```
 public void setNewImage() {

    new android.app.AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity())

            .setPositiveButton("camera", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    Intent takePicture = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
                    getActivity().startActivityForResult(takePicture, 0);
                }
            })

            .setNegativeButton("gallery", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    Intent pickPhoto = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK,
                            MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
                    getActivity().startActivityForResult(pickPhoto, 1);
                }
            })

            .show();
}
```

and here im setting the image to imageview :

```
  protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    switch (requestCode) {
        case 0:
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK && data != null && data.getData() != null) {
                Uri filePath = data.getData();
                try {
                    //Getting the Bitmap from Gallery
                    bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(getContentResolver(), filePath);

                    //Setting the Bitmap to ImageView
                    NewpostFragment.post_image.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

               /* Uri picUri = data.getData();
                filePath = getPath(picUri);
                img.setImageURI(picUri);*/

            }

            break;

        case 1:
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK && data != null && data.getData() != null) {
                /*Uri picUri = data.getData();

                filePath = getPath(picUri);

                img.setImageURI(picUri);*/



                Uri filePath = data.getData();
                try {
                    //Getting the Bitmap from Gallery
                    bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(getContentResolver(), filePath);
                    //Setting the Bitmap to ImageView
                    NewpostFragment.post_image.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

            break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, `ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE` will not give you a `Uri` via `getData()` in `onActivityResult()`. While some buggy camera apps may do that, most will not. Your choices are:

- Provide `EXTRA_OUTPUT` on the `ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE` `Intent`, in which case the photo should be stored in the location identified by the `Uri` that you put into `EXTRA_OUTPUT`, or
- Do not provide `EXTRA_OUTPUT`, and use `getParcelableExtra("data")` to get a thumbnail from the camera app

See [this sample app](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/master/Camera/FileProvider) for using `ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE` with `EXTRA_OUTPUT`.

In terms of orientation, if you go down the `EXTRA_OUTPUT` path, you can [use `android.support.media.ExifInterface`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/media/ExifInterface.html) to find out the orientation of the photo, then do something to rotate the image to match (e.g., rotate the `ImageView`).

See [this sample app](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/master/Camera/EXIFRotater) for using `ExifInterface` (though I am using a different implementation than `android.support.media.ExifInterface`).